# Using the value from a previous view in the current view

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

Long story short; I have 2 tables (**Recipe** and **RecipeIngredient**), related by the foreign key recipeId. In my MVC, if I want to see the ingredients of a recipe, I press on "Ingredients"[image: press on "Ingredients"] and a new view containing the ingredients of that certain recipe will appear.

**Index.cshtml** (Recipe)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "CreateOrEdit", "Recipe", new { id = item.id })
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Recipe", new { id = item.id })
@Html.ActionLink("Ingredients", "Index", "RecipeIngredient", new { recipeId = item.id })
```

The problem appears here; if I want to add a new ingredient, I will click on the "Add ingredients" action link which will pop up a form[image: will pop up a form].

**AddIngredient.cshtml** (RecipeIngredient)

```
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Add ingredient", "AddIngredient", "RecipeIngredient", new { Recipe recipeId })
</p>
```

> new { Recipe recipeId }

I tried this thinking that I will be able to import the variable previously used to access the ingredients of a certain recipe.

As shown in the image above, my task is to make that recipeId field get auto-generated with the Id of the previously accessed recipe. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to link the newly created ingredient with the current recipe?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am wiling to do. The newly created ingredient should have the recipeId of the current recipe.

Comment: Make you action link like this: `@Html.ActionLink("Add ingredient","AddIngredient", "RecipeIngredient", new { id = recipeId })` and in your Controller: `public AddIngredientDelete(int id) {//Your logic}`

Comment: @RahulSharma the point is that the id will then be RecipeIngredient's Id, whereas I need Recipe's ID which is a foreign key to RecipeIngredient called "recipeId". I tried using a tuple in the @ model but then I get more errors and the solution wasn't as easy as I thought because I had to remove a lot of stuff and re-do.

Comment: @Questieme Well in that case, you need to make a `ViewModel` where you would assoicate these values that come from the DB. Basically my point is that you would need to build this association in the Controller and then render your View with the Model having this association.

Comment: Harder than I thought! I will give it a try, thanks!

Comment: Did you come right?

Answer (score -1):

You could use TempData, set it when the user navigates to Recipie and read it in AddIngredient.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I will give it a try.